# Subtração de valores na mesma tabela e mesma coluna

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Eu tenho uma tabela no phpMyAdmin chamada fluxo, nessa tabela se encontra o fluxo de um caixa

[image: Amostra da tabela]

> (A descrição serviria para sabermos para que serve cada registro)

Eu preciso ter um jeito de conseguir o lucro liquido de cada mês em um período de 1 ano de forma que o primeiro registro seja o mais antigo e o ultimo o mais novo.

Eu tentei somar o lucro agrupando por mês, fazer a mesma coisa com os gastos e subtrair uma coluna da outra e só filtrar as colunas desejadas no final com SELECT:

```php
SELECT
    Valor,
    DataN
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        COALESCE((L.Valor - G.Valor),
        L.valor) AS Valor,
        MONTHNAME(L.Data) AS DataN,
        L.Data AS DATA
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            `ID`,
            SUM(`Valor`) AS Valor,
            `Data` AS DATA
        FROM
            `fluxo`
        WHERE
            `Tipo` = 'Lucro'
        GROUP BY
            YEAR(`Data`),
            MONTH(`Data`)
        ORDER BY
            YEAR(`Data`),
            MONTH(`Data`)
        DESC
    ) AS L
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT `ID`,
        SUM(`Valor`) AS Valor,
        `Data` AS DATA
    FROM
        `fluxo`
    WHERE
        `Tipo` = 'Gasto'
    GROUP BY
        YEAR(`Data`),
        MONTH(`Data`)
    ORDER BY
        YEAR(`Data`),
        MONTH(`Data`)
    DESC
) AS G
ON
    L.Data = G.Data
ORDER BY
    YEAR(L.`Data`)
DESC
    ,
    MONTH(L.`Data`)
DESC
LIMIT 12
) F
ORDER BY
    YEAR(F.`Data`) ASC,
    MONTH(F.`Data`) ASC
```

Mas algo está dando errado e não sei o que possa ser.

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo de utilização

`Select month(data) as mes, year(data) as ano, coalesce(flucro.total, 0) as lucro, coalesce(fgasto.total, 0) as gasto, (coalesce(flucro.total, 0) - coalesce(fgasto.total, 0)) as saldo from fluxo
  left join (Select Sum(valor) as total, month(data) as mes, year(data) as ano from fluxo as flucro where tipo = 'Lucro' group by 2, 3)
as flucro on month(data) = flucro.mes and year(data) = flucro.ano
  left join (Select Sum(valor) as total, month(data) as mes, year(data) as ano from fluxo as fgasto where tipo = 'Gasto' group by 2, 3)
as fgasto on month(data) = fgasto.mes and year(data) = fgasto.ano
group by 1,2 order by 1,2`

Comment: Apareceu o seguinte erro: ```#1055 - Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'flucro.total' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by```